In cilium update map return failed but map updated, and can't lookup map
Source code:
in lb.h
ret = map_update_elem(&LB4_UDP_LB_MAP, &msg_keyindex, &slot, 0);
if (!ret) {
    bpfprint("Update success");
}else {
    bpfprint("Update failed");
}
myslot = map_lookup_elem(&LB4_UDP_LB_MAP,&msg_keyindex);
if (!myslot) {
    bpfprint("Catch slot is %d",\*myslot);
}
bpfprint("Slot is %d",myslot);

Then show: "Update failed", but usebpftool map dump id` the map updated;
Next, try to lookup the map, no value found.
What is the possible reason?
Can update and lookup the map in funtion defined in lb.h

What is this map? How did you create it? Could it be that the datapath is writing to a different map from the one you're looking up with bpftool?
